# Can you help me understand the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I came across a sentence which I found hard to comprehend since English isn't my first language.

The sentence is:-

> Cleanliness is the virtue most worth having but one.

I couldn't understand the purpose of the usage of "but one" in this sentence.

I'll be grateful if you can shed some light on this.

Thank you.

Comment: It means it's the second most worth having, or the most worth having except for one. We also say *next but one* to mean the one after next. The phrase you quote is clumsy IMO but will be a reference to *cleanliness is next to godliness*.

Comment: @Minty that should probably be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I'd VTC this question but I've run out of votes for today. The meaning here should be obvious to fluent speakers, but I think it would be a most useful question on [ell.se] and is therefore worth voting for migration. Pratiek, that's not a criticism of your question but rather my suggestion for where on our SE network it's likely to help the most people :-)

Comment: @Chappo In the light of your comment, I've voted to migrate it to ELL.

Answer (score 1):

> Cleanliness is the virtue most worth having *but one*.

You can paraphrase the sentence in this way:

> Aside from one other virtue, cleanliness is the virtue most worth having.

The word [*but*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but#h2) is being used as a preposition.

> [Merriam-Webster]
> preposition
>
> **1 a** : with the exception of : BARRING
> // no one there *but* me

---

In other words:

> Cleanliness is the virtue most worth having *barring* one (other).